# QT: Problem, How do I return my own QObject derived custom class as “QVariant”?

Tags: qt

Implementing a derived “QAbstractListModel::data” method.

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myType); doesn’t even compile…. returning my custom object results in a compilation error.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
QVariant::fromValue<QObject *>(object);
```

replace QObject with your own type, but use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE on it. Keep in mind what you are declaring: the `MyType` or `MyType *`. Since you are talking about passing an object from `QAbstractItemModel::data`, then I suppose that you want to provide a pointer to the object, is this correct? If so, then declare it like this:

```
typedef MyType * MyTypeStar
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyTypeStar);
```

This will make `MyType *` known to the meta-type system.

If you want to pass around the object itself, then declare the way you tried, but make sure that you properly define your type:

> Q_DECLARE_METATYPE: This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.

Comment: "Q_DECLARE_METATYPE" is not found anywhere. I get the same build error if I declare "Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(mytype);" or "Q_DECLARE_METABURGER(myType);" It's just not found. what *.h file is it defined at?

Answer (score 2):

Why wont put it inside QVariant as QObject ? qVariantFromValue(youObjectPointer)

Comment: it doesn't compile -- /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qmetatype.h:222: error: 'qt_metatype_id' is not a member of 'QMetaTypeId<MyClass>'

Comment: Are you adding it as pointer? Remember that QObject derived classes can't be copied